# Bigger thatcher chapter number using memoir

Tags: memoir

I would like to have the thatcher chapter number a little bit bigger or better, try and check the outcome of the `tiny`, `scriptsize`, `footnotesize`, `small`...etc

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir} %Classe estilo memoir
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel} %Traduz doc para português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Reconhece acentuação
\usepackage{garamondx} %Define a nova fonte garamond
\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}

\begin{document} %=========================================================================
    \renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\thechapter}} %remove a string

    \chapter{THE TITLE OF THE CHAPTER}
        \lipsum

\end{document}
```

And is there a way to change just the number font as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}
```

to, say,

```
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\chapnumfont\HUGE\thechapter}}
```

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[14pt,twoside,a5paper,extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond} % I don't have 'garamondx' on my system
\usepackage{lipsum,microtype}

\chapterstyle{thatcher}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{\centering{\HUGE\scshape\thechapter}} % or \huge, \Huge, ...

\begin{document} 

\chapter[Short Title]{THE TITLE OF THE CHAPTER}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```